# Flex: How can I animate my List when scrolling

Tags: apache-flex, effects, flex-spark

I am using `ensureIndexIsVisible` to scroll my spark list in Flex 4.5.

How can I add animation to this scroll(Instead of just jumping to this index)?

Comment: Have you tried some of the suggestions in this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602103/scroll-to-selected-item-in-flex-4-spark-list-component

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scroll to selected item in Flex 4 Spark List component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602103/scroll-to-selected-item-in-flex-4-spark-list-component)